# If anyone take my Google Sign in token, can he or she sign in via that access token?

Tags: firebase, google-signin

I am learning react-js development, from this course I learned that I can use Firebase and Google sign as a third part storage service and sign in verification service, I draw a sign in steps with drawio diagram, as diagram below if someone take my (2) Google verification token or (6) Firebase access token can he or she sign in my website on his machine by that two tokens before expired ?

[image]

clarification about google token or firebase token security level.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue? What is the `sign in request` exactly in this case? What resources are your trying to protect? Can you edit your question and add the code for this flow so it'll give some more clarity

Comment: not a issue, I just want to get some facts about the Firebase security, It is in the React JS Development environment, and through " npm install firebase " command, I installed the firebase package into my website project. and according to the overview about the sign-in process, I draw the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty standard OAuth flow. Firebase JS SDK does the same under the hood when you call `signInWithPopup()`:

1. Getting user's access token after user's approval
2. Signing in with the response (see [sign in with OAuth credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential))

Yes, if I *somehow* get your Google Access Token (2), I can use it to access your account's data (for the scopes it has access to). Similarly, Firebase tokens are generally used as a [Bearer token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#:%7E:text=Any%20party%20in%0A%20%20%20possession%20of%20a%20bearer%20token) that means anyone in possession of the token gets access to the resources.

But chances of someone getting these tokens are slim to none (unless they have physical access to user's computer). As long as users do not share these tokens or any malicious script tries to read them, this flow has no issues.

Comment: is that means when Google Auth service generating the access token, they do not take IP or browser fingerprint into account ?

Comment: @user3226718 as mentioned, **bearer** tokens means you have the access if you have it. It's different than session based auth systems that manage auth state on server side.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer, I missed the bearer token part of your answer.